# Compiler doesn't see template specialization?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, template-specialization

I have template in my `.h` file:

```
template <typename T>
void addToolsAreaItem(){
    T* item = new T(_image, this);
    doSpecifiedStaff<T>(item);
    _tools.addTool(item);
}
```

and its specialization in `.cpp` file:

```
template <>
void ImageWorkspace::addToolsAreaItem<Preview>(){
    _preview = std::make_unique<QGraphicsView>(_splitter);
    _imagesLayout.addWidget(_preview.get());
}
```

Class `Prewiew` is empty and is used only for specialize behavior of one case (when preview button is toggled).

But I get compiler error:

```
imageworkspace.h:45: error: new initializer expression list treated as compound expression [-fpermissive]
     T* item = new T(_image, this);
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

imageworkspace.h:45: error: no matching function for call to ‘Preview::Preview(ImageWorkspace*)’
     T* item = new T(_image, this);
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Does compiler see specialization? How to fix it?

Function is called as `addToolsAreaItem<Preview>()` from sorces.

Comment: You need a forward declaration for the specialization in the header file.  Otherwise other translation units can't see it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> You need a forward declaration for the specialization in the header
>   file. Otherwise, other translation units can't see it.

–[Henri Menke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1944004/henri-menke)

```
#include "Image.h"
int main()
{
    Image::addToolsAreaItem<int>();
    system("pause");
}
```

Image.h header

```
#pragma once    
#include <iostream>

namespace Image{

    template <typename T>
    void addToolsAreaItem();

    // forward declaration
    template <>
    void addToolsAreaItem<int>();

}
```

cpp:

```
#include "Image.h"

template <typename T>
void Image::addToolsAreaItem()
{
    std::cout << typeid(T).name() << std::endl;
}

template <>
void Image::addToolsAreaItem<int>()
{
    std::cout << "Spec: int " << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

[image]